# MySQL replication with DRBD - Can we use Old master as slave after failover?

Tags: mysql, replication, clustering, failover

I have configured MySQL replication with DRBD, and now its working fine, Incase if something happens to my master then Slave will promote as Master.

My question is after the failover(lets assume after an hour), My Old master will come online, After that, will it sync the data which are modified or newly added during the downtime from my new master and Can I use it as Read replica?

Answer (score 0):

When DRBD peers reconnect they exchange and compare data generation identifiers to determine who has new data, then they will resync the differing blocks in the correct direction based on a bitmap that tracks which blocks have been modified.

By default, data on a DRBD device cannot be accessed on the `Secondary` node; only `Primary` nodes can access the device. DRBD can be configured for dual-primary, but that usually requires a clustered filesystem and some sort of node-level fencing.